# How to call a link using ID?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to get links from ids, like: 
mysite.com/view.php?url=**1234**

Automatically transfered from **1234** to **mylink.com** 
So nobody will be able to view **mylink.com** in the page source.

I was trying to find something relevant to this here but totally unsuccessful!

It should be my search terms, I'm not an expert.

**UPDATE**

I've seen this javascript working, but don't know how:

`function decode() {` 
    `var packed = document.getElementById('packed');`
    `eval("packed.value=String" + packed.value.slice(4));`
    `}`

I'm running a PHP script which is basically like this:

mysite.com/view.php?url=**mylink.com**

And the url, **mylink.com** is viewed in the source page easily, and I really want to hide it, nobody can know this **mylink.com**, because it's totally private!

Comment: have you tried some code already? if so please post what you have.

Comment: It isn't clear. What actually you don't want? If the link is hidden, how do others have the access to it or vice-versa?

Comment: AT-2016 - People won't have access to it directly, like YouTube does, practically:
www.youtube.com/watch?v=wka0YS1hQl4

Comment: Then you have to encrypt the id.

Comment: that's the problem, how can I generate ids for the links and make them accessible through my server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that will help you to understand:

```
<?php
 $query = "my=apples&are=green+and+red" ;

  foreach ( explode( '&' , $query ) as $chunk ) 
  {
      $param = explode( "=" , $chunk );

      if ( $param ) {
      printf ( "Value for parameter \"%s\" is \"%s\"<br/>\n" , urlencode ( $param[ 0 ]), urlencode( $param [1 ]));
      }
  }
?>
```

For more, see this - http://www.smarttutorials.net/encrypt-and-decrypt-stringtextids-for-url-using-php/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll be checking soon.
What does it mean: "my=apples&are=green+and+red"

Comment: It's a sample url. Nothing else.